# Why should the kernel of a ring homomorphism be an ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ring-homomorphism

so my question is: Why should the kernel be the ideal of the field $F$? Here is the required theory. Here $(a)$ means an ideal generated by $a$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: kernels of ring homomorphisms are ideals.

Comment: A basic assumption must be, I suppose, that $\;R\;$ is a commutative ring, otherwise $\;b\;$ fails.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. @DonAntonio , yes $R$ is a commutative ring.

Comment: FFR random keywords related to your question don't make a good title. It's much better to write your question, when possible. I've taken the liberty to do that for you this time... please try to do something like it in the future.

Comment: I mean, have you tried just applying the definitions?

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate on Lord Shark's comment:

Let $\phi: R \to S$ be a ring homomorphism, and let $a \in R$, $x \in \text{ker}\phi$, so $\phi(x) = 0$.

Then $\phi(ax) = \phi(a)\phi(x) = \phi(a)\cdot 0 = 0$ (since $\phi$ is a ring hom. and by the above). So $ax \in \ker\phi$.

Showing $\ker \phi$ is an additive subgroup is equally straightforward. So the kernel is an ideal --- this is usually a proposition in a first course in abstract algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi: R \to S$ be a ring homomorphism. Define ker$\phi:=\{r \in R : \phi(r)=0\}$.

Let $a,b \in$ ker$\phi$ then $\phi(a-b)=\phi(a)-\phi(b)=0-0=0 \Rightarrow a - b \in$ ker$\phi$.

Similarly let $r \in R, a \in$ ker$\phi$. Then

$\phi(ra)=\phi(r)\phi(a)=\phi(r)0=0$ thus $ra \in$ ker$\phi$, by similar argument we can show $ar \in$ ker$\phi$ making it an ideal.

Comment: A downvote without comment is pointless. Why the downvote? This proof is perfectly valid.

Comment: Yes, the first part show that ker. is additive subgroup, vote +1

Comment: @Tim thank you :)